# What is a good way of tracking link clicks in Asp.Net Mvc app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scripting, click

I have an MVC app with several `<a>` tags, and I want to have a way of tracking link clicks, preferably without doing redirects (i.e., without changing link addresses). Is there any way this can be done? And, if not, is there any way one can get this functionality automatically (e.g., with javascript)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Taking your other wishes in consideration, this should be your way to go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  //On document ready
    $('a').click(function(e) {  //For each a (anchor), set the following function
        urchinTracker (this.href); 
        pageTracker._trackPageview (this.href);
        //Custom tracker here?
        return true; //To keep following href definitions
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the difference between returning `true` and `false` on execution?

Answer (score 1):

**Since you are already using Google Analytics**, they have a javascript function to put in the `onclick` event.

The method name is either `urchinTracker` or `pageTracker._trackPageview` depending on whether you are using `urchin.js` or `ga.js` as your Analytics script include.

An example (from [here](http://www.iqcontent.com/blog/2006/11/tracking-document-downloads-in-google-analytics/)) in both formats:

```
<a href="/files/map.pdf" onClick="javascript:urchinTracker ('/downloads/map');">
<a href="/files/map.pdf" onClick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview ('/downloads/map');">
```

Basically what that does is call the javascript method (which does the 'analytics call' to Google's server) then does the `<a>` action as normal (ie. whatever the link was supposed to do - in this case open PDF files).

Is that what you are looking for - or is the jQuery answer what you wanted?

**EDIT:** in response to your question, [this post](http://www.iqcontent.com/blog/2006/11/tracking-document-downloads-in-google-analytics/) contains a non-jQuery javascript include ([here](http://www.iqcontent.com/blog/files/taglinks.js)) that looks for 'downloadable files' and adds tracking. If you want to use jQuery, check out the other answer by [ropstah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45311/ropstah) since he/she has updated their answer to be Google Analytics-specific.

Comment: Actually, this is pretty good! Can you suggest a way of automatically adding the onClick handler using jQuery? I can't go through all pages and add an onClick handler to each anchor tag, so I'm guessing there ought to be a jQuery way of doing this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics): you can't do any better.

Comment: I'm already using GA, but if the link goes off-site or downloads a local resource (e.g., a PDF), I can't track it.